# Illuminated cloud fails to resolve labels

Tags: customlabel, label, illuminatedcloud

I have a problem with my labels on my project. I use IntelliJ with Illuminated Cloud

I've read some topics on this subject, and guys just resolve their problems by regenerating Offline Symbol, or just because they don't retrieved labels in their project before.

I've my labels in my project :

[image]

I regenerated Offline Symbol Table many times but my labels are still reds, only my labels.
My collegues have the same problem.

Someone have suggestion ?

Thx for help !

Comment: Best place for support with IC is the [Q&A group](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/g/qanda).

Comment: Thx @PhilW , I'll take a look, I don't know this group

Comment: It is the best place since you can directly interact with Scott Wells, the author of IC.

Answer (score 1):

I'll see if I can offer an answer here, but if my suggestion doesn't work, definitely reach out via the Q&A group or support email.

Labels are resolved against either the local label metadata files for unpackaged labels or the generated OST for labels from installed packages. I'm assuming you're likely trying to resolve/complete against local labels? If so, make sure that you've retrieved the `CustomLabels` metadata into the project. There *may* be a bug with over-aggressive caching, so go ahead and restart the IDE process after retrieving to ensure the cache is properly populated.

If that doesn't help resolve it, feel free to reach out via one of the support channels and I'll be happy to help get it resolved ASAP.

Comment: Hi @ScottWells, thanks for the reply, but that didn't solve my problem.
I'm gonna try by the Q&A group

Comment: After re-reading your message several times, I think I understood one thing.
You say "Labels are resolved against either the local label metadata files for unpackaged labels or the generated OST for labels from installed packages."
My problem is with unwrapped labels, so IC and OST are not the cause of my problem. I have several "CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml" files in different folders in my project.
Is there a conf file or something like that, where to set preferences regarding labels?

Sry for my english, I try to do my best, thx for help.

Comment: Hi, @AdrienDestouesse. I'm not sure what the exact protocol is for back-and-forth discussion in pursuit of a resolution here in StackExchange. Why don't you reach out directly via the support email listed at https://www.illuminatedcloud.com/support and I'll help figure out what's going on, then we can circle back here with the exact resolution for anyone else with the same problem who might be using this post in the future.